# Find all Nearest nodes to Yaxis abaqus python scripting

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

In the following figure a nodeset is created which contains all the nodes belonging to a face.
[image]

I would like to present a curve showing the position of the maximum temperature Tmax along the "Y" direction.
To do this I started by writing this script to detect the position of Tmax. Then I defined a local coordinate system whose Y direction passes through the node having the maximum temperature Tmax.

```
path0='1101.odb'
odb=openOdb(path=path0)

nodeset='NODESET-ZCT'
mySet = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodeSets[nodeset]
lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]
TEMP=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['NT11']
mySetTemp = TEMP.getSubset(region=mySet)
mySetTempValues=mySetTemp.values
coords=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['COORD']
mySetCoord = coords.getSubset(region=mySet)
mySetCoordValues=mySetCoord.values

Tmax = 0
for v in mySetTempValues:
    if v.data > Tmax:
        Tmax = v.data
        NodeTmax=v.nodeLabel
print(NodeTmax,Tmax)
#print('Tint_max est =', Tmax)
for var in  mySetCoordValues:
    if var.nodeLabel==NodeTmax:
        COORD_node_Tmax=var.data
print(NodeTmax,Tmax,COORD_node_Tmax)

CSYS_Tmax=odb.rootAssembly.DatumCsysByThreePoints(name='CSYS-Tmax', 
    coordSysType=CARTESIAN, origin=(COORD_node_Tmax[0], 0.0, 0.0), point1=(0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0), point2=(COORD_node_Tmax[0],COORD_node_Tmax[1],COORD_node_Tmax[2]))
```

My objective is to find all the nodes nearest to the "Y" axis, extract their positions and then represent T=f(Y). I should have a curve like this:
[image]

Can you help me complete this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one possible way you could get that curve. 
However, you require threshold distance to identify the nearest nodes to the highest value point.

1. First get the data as Array along with coordinates:
   You can use `writeFieldReport` command to output the data in CSV format.

```
# Show odb first in the viewport
viewport.setValues(displayedObject=subodb)

# Set formatting report options to CSV
num_fmt = NumberFormat(numDigits=6, precision=0, format=SCIENTIFIC)
session.fieldReportOptions.setValues(printTotal=OFF, printMinMax=OFF, 
    numberFormat=num_fmt, reportFormat=COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES)

# Get the display group object
ndset_name = 'NODESET-ZCT'
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo

if odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodeSets.has_key(ndset_name):
    nset_name_leaf = 'PART-1-1' + '.' + ndset_name
elif odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets.has_key(ndset_name):
    nset_name_leaf = ndset_name

node_leaf = dgo.LeafFromNodeSets(nodeSets=(nset_name_leaf,))
dgrp = session.DisplayGroup(name='node_leaf', leaf=node_leaf)

session.writeFieldReport(fileName='output.csv', append=OFF,
    sortItem='Node Label', odb=subodb, step=0, frame=0, outputPosition=NODAL,
    variable=(('NT11', NODAL), ), displayGroup=dgrp)
```

2. Read the data and manipulate data:

```
dat = numpy.loadtxt('output.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(4, 6, 11))
# 4th column is Node Label, 6 - Y coordinate and 11 is NT11.

# Find max node point and substract y coordinate from all Y-data
dat[:, 1] = dat[:, 1] - dat[numpy.argmax(dat[:, 2])][1]

# Threshold Y distance to identify the nearest nodes
delta = 0.6
dat[dat[:, 1] <= delta]
# Now you can plot the data as 2nd as X axis and 4th as Y axis.
```

Please make the appropriate changes in the code while exporting data to CSV.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply. an error is displayed about showing odb in the viewport : "name viewport is not defined"

Comment: Few objects are not defined in the above code as it is a representative code to show you one possible way. Viewport is a viewport object and also subodh is odb object in the above code. Please modify accordingly and try.

Comment: If this solved your problem, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: ,Thank you. The previous error was resolved
But, when I try to generate the csv file containing the results I got the following error : "No report has been generated"

Comment: Ahh... As your node set is at instance level, node leaf object must be created as `node_leaf = dgo.LeafFromNodeSets(nodeSets=('PART-1-1'+'.'+ndset_name,))`. Same thing I have updated in my answer.

Comment: Great, the csv file is created now. Thanks. I'll try the rest of the code and i will let you know.

Comment: Now, to present NT11 as function of Y coordinate. Should I use the XYplot object function? Can you please help me to choose the appropriate function and to plot this curve?

Comment: Yes. You can explore XY plot options. First, export y-coord and NT11 in a text file using `numpy.savetxt('output.dat', dat)`. Then create xy object using `session.XYDataFromFile` method (explore this). Then create XY plot `xx = session.XYPlot(name='my_xyplot')` then access the chart object `chart1 = xx.charts['Chart-1']`. Add the curve `c1 = session.Curve(name='my_curve', xyData = xydata)` and add curve to plot `chart1.setValues(curvesToPlot=(c1, ), )`.  Then show plot in viewport `viewport.setValues(displayedObject=xx)`. Perform these operations manually in Abaqus CAE, you'll get the code.